# Generate Zeroes when no rows where selected

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, isnull

Good Day Every one

i have this code

```
 SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,4,AE.LOAN)) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.ID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.KGRAM,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.AMOUNT,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM  #AllExpired AE
    INNER JOIN Transactions.ITEM PIT
    ON AE.MAINID=PIT.MAINID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.HISTO PH
    ON AE.MAINID=PH.MAINID
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,(DATEADD(MM,4,AE.LOAN)))

UNION ALL

/*SELECT EXPIRED AFTER 5 MONTHS*/
SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,5,AE.LOAN)) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.ID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.KGRAM,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.AMOUNT,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM #ExpAfterFiveMonths E5 
    INNER JOIN Transactions.ITEM PIT
    ON E5.MAINID=PIT.MAINID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.HISTO PH
    ON E5.MAINID=PH.MAINID
    INNER JOIN #AllExpired AE
    ON AE.MAINID=E5.MAINID
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,(DATEADD(MM,5,AE.LOAN)))

UNION ALL

/*SELECT EXPIRED AFTER 6 MONTHS*/
SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,6,AE.LOAN)) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.ID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.KGRAM,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.AMOUNT,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM #ExpAfterSixMonths E6
    INNER JOIN Transactions.ITEM PIT
    ON E6.MAINID=PIT.MAINID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.HISTO PH
    ON E6.MAINID=PH.MAINID
    INNER JOIN #AllExpired AE
    ON AE.MAINID=E6.MAINID
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,(DATEADD(MM,6,AE.LOAN)))
```

and it works fine, the problem is that when the Select statements retrieved no rows they become empty instead of replacing zeroes

instead of Generating the word month with 0 0 0 it just pops out empty in which i dont like,,

can you help me achive that? the result should be something like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------  
MONTH        |   Count  |      Grams   |     Principal |  
October      |123123    |     123123   | 123123213     |
November     | 0        |       0      |      0        | // this should appear if no rows where selected instead of blank
```

here is my code to generate the items inside temptables

```
SELECT TE.MAINID
       ,TE.EXPIRY
       ,TE.LOAN
       ,PM.STORAGE
into #AllExpiredAfterFiveAndSix
FROM #ExpiredAfterFiveandSixMon TE
    inner join Transactions.TABLEMAIN PM
    on TE.MAINID = PM.MAINID
     inner join #AllExpired E4
     on E4.MAINID=TE.MAINID
WHERE ((cast(TE.EXPIRY as date) < cast(TE.newloandate as date)) 
      OR(TE.NewLoanDate is null and ((cast(TE.EXPIRY as date) < cast(PM.DATERED as date)) or PM.STATUS = 7 or PM.STATUS = 5)) ) 
      AND (PM.STORAGE BETWEEN 3 AND 14 OR PM.STORAGE=17)


/*EXPIRED AFTER 5 MONTHS*/
select AE.MAINID
        ,AE.LOAN
        ,AE.STORAGE
        ,ae.EXPIRY
into #ExpAfterFiveMonths
from #AllExpiredAfterFiveAndSix AE
    inner join #AllExpired E4
    on E4.MAINID=AE.MAINID
where MONTH(AE.EXPIRY)= MONTH(dateadd(mm,1,E4.EXPIRY))
 /*EXPIRED AFTER 6 MONTHS*/     
select AE.MAINID
        ,AE.LOAN
        ,AE.STORAGE
        ,ae.EXPIRY
into #ExpAfterSixMonths
from #AllExpiredAfterFiveAndSix AE
     inner join #AllExpired E4
     on E4.MAINID=AE.MAINID
where MONTH(AE.EXPIRY)= MONTH(dateadd(mm,2,E4.EXPIRY))

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ExpAfterFiveMonths ON #ExpAfterFiveMonths(MAINID)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ExpAfterSixMonths ON #ExpAfterSixMonths(MAINID)
```

i hope you can help me because im just a starter in sql

i have tried using is NULL as what you have seen above but i do not know if i implement it correctly

Hoping for your Kindness and consideration thank you :)

****EDIT**

The temp tables contains no values to start with, i just want it to output 0 instead of blank.

Comment: Can you post the schema of your permanent tables?

Comment: @LloydBanks what do you mean by schema? im sorry im new in t-sql

Comment: The layout of the tables, so the column names and their types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:  Added a months table to handle empty temp tables.

Change inner joins to left joins.

```
DECLARE @months TABLE (ReportMonth VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @months VALUES 
('January'),('February'),('March'),('April'),
('May'),('June'),('July'),('August'),
('September'),('October'),('November'),('December')


SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ COALESCE(DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,4,AE.fld_LoanDate)), M.ReportMonth) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.fld_PawnItemID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.fld_KaratGram,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.fld_PrincipalAmt,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM 
    @months M
    LEFT JOIN #AllExpired AE
    ON M.ReportMonth = DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,4,AE.fld_LoanDate))
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    ON AE.fld_PawnMainID=PIT.fld_PawnMainID
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PH
    ON AE.fld_PawnMainID=PH.fld_PawnMainID
GROUP BY M.ReportMonth

UNION ALL

/*SELECT EXPIRED AFTER 5 MONTHS*/
SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ 'Expired Item -'+ COALESCE(DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,5,AE.fld_LoanDate)), M.ReportMonth) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.fld_PawnItemID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.fld_KaratGram,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.fld_PrincipalAmt,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM 
    @months M
    LEFT JOIN #AllExpired AE
    ON M.ReportMonth = DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,5,AE.fld_LoanDate))
    LEFT JOIN #ExpAfterFiveMonths E5 
    ON AE.fld_PawnMainID=E5.fld_PawnMainID
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    ON E5.fld_PawnMainID=PIT.fld_PawnMainID
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PH
    ON E5.fld_PawnMainID=PH.fld_PawnMainID
GROUP BY M.ReportMonth

UNION ALL

/*SELECT EXPIRED AFTER 6 MONTHS*/
SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ COALESCE(DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,6,AE.fld_LoanDate)), M.ReportMonth) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(PIT.fld_PawnItemID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PIT.fld_KaratGram,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(PH.fld_PrincipalAmt,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM 
    @months M
    LEFT JOIN #AllExpired AE
    ON M.ReportMonth = DateName(mm,DATEADD(MM,6,AE.fld_LoanDate))
    LEFT JOIN #ExpAfterSixMonths E6
    ON AE.fld_PawnMainID=E6.fld_PawnMainID
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    ON E6.fld_PawnMainID=PIT.fld_PawnMainID
    LEFT JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PH
    ON E6.fld_PawnMainID=PH.fld_PawnMainID    
GROUP BY M.ReportMonth
```

Comment: If the AE table has no data, then there is no monthname to select.  You need to build a table of months that you expect to be on the report.

Comment: I built a table of months to handle the empty temp table case.

Comment: you are right now i understand :) i awarded you the bounty thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your select

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (AE.fld_LoanDate IS null) THEN 0 ELSE AE.fld_LoanDate END) as fld_LoanDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Though both answers do what the questioner wanted, I though I would suggest 'where LoanDate in (range)', 'group by', along with left join, and a date range.

So, you have tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tPawnItem
(
    fPawnItemID int auto_increment primary key,
    fDescription varchar(30),
    fKaratGram float
);
CREATE TABLE tPawnHisto
(
    fPawnMainID int primary key,
    fPrincipalAmt int,
    fRedeemed date
);
create table tExp
(
    fPawnMainID int primary key,
    fLoanDate date
);
```

This is proximately what I'm suggesting (I don't have my laptop, so no mysql right now),

```
SELECT 
    'Expired Item -'+ DATENAME(MM,tExp.fLoanDate) as [Month]
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(tPawnItem.fPawnItemID,0))'COUNT'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(tPawnItem.fKaratGram,0))'GRAMS'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(tPawnHisto.fPrincipalAmt,0))'PRINCIPAL'
FROM  tExp
    INNER JOIN tPawnItem
    ON tExp.fPawnMainID=tPawnItem.fPawnMainID
    INNER JOIN tPawnHisto
    ON tExp.fPawnMainID=tPawnHisto.fPawnMainID
WHERE t.Exp.fLoanDate in (
    DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(MM,4,tExp.fLoanDate)),
    DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(MM,5,tExp.fLoanDate)),
    DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(MM,6,tExp.fLoanDate)),
    DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(MM,7,tExp.fLoanDate))
)
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,tExp.fLoanDate);
```